# Тире в простом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире

Почему ставится тире в предложении: "Размер у дивана около двух метров в длину"?

Answer (score 1):

Тире здесь может замещать пропущенный глагол "составляет" (размер дивана *составляет* столько-то; предлог не нужен).

> Размер дивана — около двух метров в длину.

Другая возможность — поставить двоеточие:

> Размер дивана (вот какой): около двух метров в длину.

Answer (score 1):

Размер дивана — около двух метров в длину.

Тире ставится согласно основному правилу по теме "Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым" http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

4. Тире ставится, если оба главных члена предложения выражены **количественными числительными или если один из них выражен формой именительного падежа существительного, а другой — числительным либо оборотом с числительным:** Двадцать лет — хорошая вещь (Сим.); Расставанья и встречи — две главные части, из которых когда-нибудь сложится счастье (Долм.); Трижды пять — пятнадцать; Скорость — шестьдесят километров в час.

**Примечание**. В специальной литературе при характеристике предмета тире в этом случае часто не ставится: Грузоподъёмность крана 2,5 тонны, вылет стрелы 5 метров; Температура плавления золота 1063о С.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение составлено не совсем корректно.

1. "Размер у дивана" следует заменить на "размер дивана" (размер чего?).
2. Размер дивана определяется не только его длиной. Если речь только о длине, то лучше так и сказать:

**Длина дивана — около двух метров.**